# wait() in C. What args should i pass to it

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

What arguments should i pass to wait() so that it waits for all child processes to terminate before continuing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wait` only waits for a single child. You should call `wait(NULL)` in a loop until it returns `-1` with `errno == ECHILD`:

```
while (wait(NULL) != -1 || errno != ECHILD) { }
```

From the [wait(2) manual page:](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)

> ```
> ECHILD (for wait())
> ```
>
> The calling
>   process does not have any unwaited-for
>   children.
>
> ```
> EINTR
> ```
>
> WNOHANG was not set and an
>   unblocked signal or a SIGCHLD was
>   caught; see signal(7).

As such, you must check for ECHILD, lest you be fooled by a caught signal.

Comment: why should the errno be ECHILD

Comment: @user465983, added citation for ECHILD

Comment: why do you do wait(NULL) without any arguments?

Comment: @user465983, read the manual page I linked - the meaning of the argument (and there is an argument there) is explained within

Comment: Passing `NULL` rather than `&status` is probably a bad idea, unless you really don't care how/why the children died.

Comment: @R, if all the OP wants to do is wait for them to exit, there's no need to know the status code. *shrug*